# Which Git Hooks are supported by the VS Code built-in Git extension?

Tags: git, vscode-extensions, githooks

It would seem to me that only a few of the Git hooks are supported by the built-in Git extension for VS Code, for example, `pre-commit` and `pre-base` hook seem to be, yet others like `post-checkout`, `post-merge` and `post-rewrite` seem not to be.

I added very simple implementations, i.e. just echo a message, for many of these hooks and only a few seem to trigger at the appropriate intervals for when I would normally expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use my extension [GitHook VsCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lakshmikanthayyadevara.githooks) , this enable to toggle git hooks and run then from command line